When do Mushroom Challenges happen?
Every few turns Tumble appears and offers a Mushroom Challenges to earn more mushrooms. Is there any pattern to when these challenges are offered or is it random chance?


Mushroom Challenges occur every three turns.

Shortest informative answer ever.
